# Find and extract an amount from a string

Tags: c#

I have to find an amount from a string.

```
string s = "I was paid $17,000 for the work.";
```

Code should extract `$17,000`. How can i do this?

Comment: Could you post code of what you've tried so far and explain why it isn't working/what exact problem you're experiencing?

Comment: You could use a regular expression. Try to write one, you can test it using http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone writes something like "I was paid $17/hr for the work, totaling $350"?

Comment: Is "$" the only currency? What about "USD 25,000" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try regular expressions:

```
string sentence = "I was paid $17,000 for the work.";
string amount = Regex.Match(sentence, @"\$\d+,\d+").Value;
```

I used pattern `\$\d+,\d+` to match dollar sign, digits, comma, and again digits.

You could also use `\$[^ ]+` which will match dollar sign and then one or more characters different from space, this solution is more general.

Comment: @OP Mind that this is very specific to your example. It will not find amounts with "cents" (e.g. "$23.50") and it will not find other currencies. Even "USD" instead of "$" wouldn't be found.

Answer (score 2):

you can use The Regex.Split method

```
// Split on one or more non-digit characters.

string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

check out :[This code sample](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split-numbers)

Comment: Please don't post Link-Only Answers. They are considered low quality and generally are frowned upon. Consider citing the relevant parts of your code example in the answer.

Comment: It will split 17,000 to 17 and 000.